# How to send a message with priority with Spring cloud stream binder

Tags: rabbitmq, priority-queue, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using **rabbitmq**. I've defined a queue with priority, but when I have to send a message with priority, I don't know how to specify the priority on it.

This is my code

**StreamProcessor.java**

```
public interface StreamProcessor {
  public static final String TEST_JOB_OUTPUT = "test-job-output";

  @Output(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB_OUTPUT)
  MessageChannel testJobOutput();

}
```

**MessageSender.java**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB_OUTPUT)
private MessageChannel testJobOutput;

public void sendMessage(String s, MessagePriority priority) {
    testJobOutput.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).build());      
}
```

I've tried to specify an header, "x-priority" on the message, but don't seems to work.

```
public void sendMessage(String s, MessagePriority priority) {
        testJobOutput.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).setHeader("x-priority", 10).build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by try and failure... It's **priority** not **x-priority**

```
public class MessageSender {

    public static final String MESSAGE_HEADER_PRIORITY = "priority";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB_OUTPUT)
    private MessageChannel testJobOutput;

    public void sendMessage(String s, MessagePriority priority) {
        testJobOutput.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).setHeader(MESSAGE_HEADER_PRIORITY, priority.value()).build());
    }

}
```